# Is there a non-brute-force solution to this single-valued random variable transformation problem?

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, multinomial-distribution

*Note:*   I'm happy to edit and rename the “question title” for this problem if someone proposes a better (and concise) way of asking about this problem.

In brief, the problem I'm presenting below was posted on this site (or maybe on mathematics), but it appears to have been hidden or deleted (it was most likely a homework problem).  However, I tried my hand at it, and while I solved it, I'm fairly certain there is a far more elegant solution than the essentially brute-force approach I used.

**The Problem**
You make and sell widgets.  You have $n=100$ clients each month.  For the upcoming month, a client can place one of three orders:  $k_1=2$ widgets, $k_2=3$ widgets, or $k_3=4$ widgets.  The distribution of the orders is multinomial with $p_1=p_2=p_3=\frac13$.  ¿How many widgets do you need to make in a month to be 95% confident that you can fulfill the orders for your 100 clients?

**Converting to (Conventional) Mathematical Notation**
We have a multivariate random variable for the orders:
$$\left(A,B,C\right) \sim \text{MultiNom}(n,p_1=p_2=p_3=\frac13)$$
We transform this (essentially) bivariate random variable to a single-valued random variable:
$$f(X) = 2A+3B+4C=2A + 3(100-A-C) + 4C = C-A + 300$$
The problem can now be written as, find minimum $x$ (where $x$ is the number of widgets over the average of 300), such that
$$Pr(X\ge x+300)<0.05$$

**Brute-Force Solution**
Let’s look at a few examples:

- If $x=100$, then $(a,b,c)=(0,0,100)$
- If $x=99$, then $(a,b,c)=(0,1,99)$
- If $x=98$, then $(a,b,c)$ is either $(1,0,99)$ or $(0,2,98)$
- If $x=97$, then $(a,b,c)$ is either $(1,1,98)$ or $(0,3,97)$

Extending this pattern, we have for $X=x$, the possibilities for $(a,b,c)$ are

- If $x$ is even, $(0,100-x,x)$, $(1,100-x-2,x+1)$, ... $\left(\frac {100-x}2,0,\frac {100+x}2\right)$
- If $x$ is odd, $(0,100-x,x)$, $(1,100-x-2,x+1)$, ... $\left(\frac {99-x}2,1,\frac {99+x}2\right)$

To obtain $Pr(X=x)$, we simply use the multinomial distribution and sum the probabilities of observing these patterns of $(a,b,c)$.

Using R to obtain these probabilities

```
n <- 100
probs <- rep.int(0,n+1)
for(X in n:0) {
    ctr_x = n-X+1
    for(ctr_j in 1:ceiling(ctr_x/2)) {
        a <- ctr_j-1
        c <- X+a
        b <- n - a - c
        probs[ctr_x] <- probs[ctr_x] + dmultinom(c(a,b,c),prob=c(1,1,1))
    }
}
```

We can use

```
plot(n:0,cumsum(probs),type="b",
     xlim=c(0,20),xlab="orders over average",
     ylab="(rev) cumulative probability")
abline(h=0.05)
abline(v=14)
```

to obtain the following plot:
[image: reverse cumulative probability]
And we can see that the solution would be at $x=14$

```
> cumsum(probs)[101-13:15]
[1] 0.06285299 0.04904713 0.03777050
```

Which is to say $Pr(X\ge 314) = 0.049$ and $Pr(X\ge 313) = 0.063$.  Thus, if we want to be 95% confident that we can fulfill the month’s orders, we need to product 313 each month.

Again, if you can share a more elegant solution, I would be very interested.

Comment: I remember the original post and recall thinking it was looking for a Normal approximation, which will be *extremely* accurate. Indeed, the mean is $3$ and the variance is $2/3.$ Thus, the expected sum of $100$ orders is $300$ and its variance is $200/3.$ The Normal approximation gives $300 + Z_{0.95}\sqrt{300/3}=313.43.$ Your answer is far from that, so please double-check it. For an efficient exact solution, use the FFT, as in `f <- fft(c(c(1/3,1/3,1/3), rep(0,253)));
fn <- Re(fft(f^100, inverse=TRUE))/length(f);
x <- seq_along(fn)+2*100-1;
plot(x, cumsum(fn), xlim=c(270, 330))`

Comment: Apologies...$x$ is actually the value over the mean (of 300).  I've updated the post accordingly.  And thus, this approximation is indeed the answer that is provided above.

Comment: Good -- but you're off by one.  If you produce only 313 per month, there is only a 93.7% chance you will meet all the orders.  In the Normal approximation, to be assured of reaching the 95% threshold, you would round the value of $313.43$ up to $314,$ which is the correct answer.  Your algorithm, btw, is identical to mine (both are brute force) but is less efficient.

Comment: If Pr(X ≥ 314) = 0.049 is correct, then Pr(X < 314) = 1 - 0.049 = 0.951.  Thus, there is a more than 95% chance of fulfilling the order.  ¿Are you saying this value is wrong?  If so, then I'm unclear how we have the same algorithm.

Comment: I have confirmed with your code that the answer is indeed 313.  ```cbind(x,1-cumsum(fn))[113:115,] ``` gives the same results as I have shown above.  Thus, if you produce 313 items, there is a 95.1% chance that you will be able to fulfill all orders.  The answer does not need to be "rounded-up" to 314.